# Are there any commonly available and supported backlit, monochrome graphic LCDs with more than 128x64 pixels?

Tags: display

I am currently using a ST7565 graphic LCD for display in a heat pump system.

This LCD has the following characteristics:

- 128x64 pixels
- 2.5"x1.5"
- monochrome, no greyscale
- backlit
- good viewing angles
- serially connected (i.e. only uses a small number of pins)
- high enough refresh rate to show animated icons
- low cost (£20)
- has a high-quality, maintained library
- available from multiple sources for several years

I am finding the resolution of the screen limiting for my application. Ideally I would like a display that is exactly the same but with a higher resolution. Something between

I do not want:

- colour (largely as the display is less visible, but also increased cost and code complexity), but red/green/blue on black would be OK.
- a physically smaller display (all of the OLED displays are small - 2" and below) as it needs to be visible from a distance

Are there any displays that meet these requirements?

I hope that the specific requirements here mean that this is not a simple "[shopping question](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-should-questions-be-considered-shopping-recommendations)".

Comment: OLED displays may be smaller, but their much higher brightness makes them readable from a bit further comparatively speaking.

Comment: I tested a 1.8" OLED display next to the 2.5" LCD and found that the LCD was much easier to read in a room with daylight.

Comment: OLED > LCD --> microview.io

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find a bunch of displays at [new haven display](http://www.newhavendisplay.com/oled-graphic-oled-c-119_577.html?zenid=jpvgfaffukfrnbam6l9mnkbqg1), which are big and OLED and not too expensive:

- [2.7" 128x64 OLED](http://www.newhavendisplay.com/images/NHD-2.7-12864UCY3-front-NOBL.jpg)
- [3.12" 256x64 OLED](http://www.newhavendisplay.com/nhd31225664umy3-p-6092.html)

Those OLED Displays have a really excellent viewing angle and can be read from far (given you accept those sizes, which are >2").

Otherwise, the biggest I know about are [LCD ones from NHD](http://www.newhavendisplay.com/lcd-graphic-c-21.html) over there:

- [320x240 LCD with backlight](http://www.newhavendisplay.com/lcd-graphic-320-x-240-c-21_107.html)

What's good with them, it's that they can cope with production in case this is needed, their prices are decent and their product just work(cTMr). You can find the [u8g library](https://code.google.com/p/u8glib/) to run them.

Comment: Unfortunately they all seem to be parallel rather than serial. I think I might have to resign myself to using a larger ATmega.

Comment: no they aren't. The [NHD12864-2.7](http://www.newhavendisplay.com/specs/NHD-2.7-12864UCY3.pdf) can be controlled using 4 wires, and the NHD320240 can be controlled with less pins as well, looking at the [S1D13700 Driver's datasheet](http://www.newhavendisplay.com/app_notes/S1D13700.pdf) (never tried that one, but I'm using the former in serial mode and it works very well).

Comment: The NHD12864-2.7 doesn't satisfy the requirement of being higher resolution though. All the connection diagrams seem to show D7:0 being connected in the S1D13700 data sheet, don't they?

Comment: hm.. looking again, I may have thought wrongly. Indeed, the NHD12864-2.7 is not of a higher resolution, but it's an OLED bigger than 2", and you've got the 3.12" displays, which are wider but having a better resolution (256x64).

Comment: N.B.: you may use an i2c port expander as well, or a small cheaper AVR as interface.

Comment: by the way, you can check also the [supported display list](https://code.google.com/p/u8glib/wiki/device) of the u8glib project, to help you make a choice. They got a few big displays.